# Bazel Tensorflow installation from source: Unrecognized option: --host_force_python=py2

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to install tensorflow from source. When running the configure file I selected all the default parameters, then when trying to run:

```
bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I get the message:

```
INFO: Reading options for 'build' from /home/ubuntu/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc:
  'build' options: --force_python=py2 --host_force_python=py2 --python2_path=/usr/bin/python --define=use_fast_cpp_protos=true --define=allow_oversize_protos=true --define PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python --spawn_strategy=standalone --genrule_strategy=standalone
Unrecognized option: --host_force_python=py2
```

Then when I try to run the build_pip_package command, it can't findthe build_pip_package command:

```
build_pip_package: command not found
```

Although there does exist a build_pip_package file inside `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package`

Comment: Just to be clear, you did run `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg`, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being clear, I first ran `bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package` and then `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg`, for which I got the error `-bash: bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the Bazel you're using doesn't know about the `--host_force_python` flag.  The flag was [added in January](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/27bdc238e5855a25e54f1e7300beebb2f17bcab7), is it possible you're using an old version of Bazel?  You can check with `bazel version`, make sure you're using at least 0.1.4 (optimally you'd be using [0.3.0](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases)).

Alternatively, you could just open up `/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc` and remove the line `build --host_force_python=py2`, but I don't know how necessary that line is (so that might cause other problems).

Comment: There is also the option `--bazelrc=/dev/null` to ignore the configuration file. See https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#bazelrc